# Angular2 search add boolean to map valuechanges

Tags: javascript, angular, search, rxjs, angular2-services

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.data(term), this.variable = true)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.variable = false;

      });
```

In the above code i want to make the `this.variable` to true when the this.data observable method is being called. This is the way i tried but it gives error that it's not a observable method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you wanted to do with `switchMap` but if you want to initialize an Observable chain you can use `startWith()` operator.

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .startWith(true)
```

Or if you want to always pass only true value you can use `mapTo`:

```
this.searchField.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .mapTo(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use do operator

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do

```
 this.searchField.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.data(term))
  .do(x => this.variable = true)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.variable = false;

  });
```

Comment: This is not changing the value of  `this.variable` to true when `this.data(term)` observable method is called